# Можно ли использовать С++ для мобильных платформ?

Tags: c++, мобильная-разработка

Можно ли использовать *С++* для написания приложений под *Android* или *iOS*? Что для этого нужно? Знаю, что для этого лучше подходит *Java*, но все же, реально ли писать полноценные приложения на мобильные устройств на *С++*?

Comment: Реально. Вариантов множество от фреймворков типо Qt или cocos до сборки через ndk в исполняемый файл.

Comment: Для iOS Java не вариант, кмк.

Comment: Собственно под iOS Obj-C это чистое расширение С поэтому можно и на голом писать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и в некоторых случаях даже необходимо. В основном это касается ситуаций низкой производительности. Для Android это обеспечивается при помощи NDK. Более подробно можно почитать например на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/203014/).

Comment: Ну необходимость обычно есть критичные фрагменты выносить в .so а не писать полностью...

Comment: @pavel а кто говорит про `писать полностью`?

Comment: Значит я немного не так понял вопрос.

Comment: @pavel ну, может бы я тоже его не так понял :)

Comment: @alexolut, подробнее можно? Как например, это происходит? Нужен какой-то доп эмулятор, ведь андроид студио работает только под явой

Comment: @IWProgrammer ну и вопрос конечно) 1 - андроид студия работает с С в том числе. 2 - а что нету других IDE? эклипс тот же. Я вон вообще в блокноте писать люблю...